# jQuery exclude selector matches from #find results

Tags: jquery, find

How best would I exclude results from #other_section, given a structure like this?

```
<form>
  <input id=one>
  <div id=other_section>
    <input id=two>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a possible API:

```
inputs = @find(":input").exclude("#other_section :input")
```

Comment: There are many ways to interpret your question. Can you please provide an example or two of what you would like to have happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':input:not(#other_section > :input)');
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/5XCcF/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
$.fn.exclude = (selector)->
  excluded_items = @end().find(selector)
  @filter ->
    !_.include(excluded_items, this)
```